# Из JSONObject в array

Tags: android, java, массивы

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
{"converter":[
    {"name":"Масса",
      "valnames":{
          "mm":"Миллиметры",
          "cm":"Сантиметры",
          "dm":"Дециметры",
          "m":"Метры",
          "km":"Километры",
          "inch":"Дюймы",
          "foot":"Футы"
      },
      "valint":{
          "mm":"1",
          "cm":"10",
          "dm":"100",
          "m":"1000",
          "km":"1000000",
          "inch":"25.4",
          "foot":"304.8"
      }
    }
]}
```

Вот код:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray data  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("converter");
JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
final String name=c.getString("name");
JSONObject valnames = c.getJSONObject("valnames");
JSONObject valint = c.getJSONObject("valint");
```

Количество значений в объектах valnames и valint одинаково, но сколько, не известно.

Как мне их по порядку занести в массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ключи в обоих объектах одинаковы, то как-то так:

```
Iterator<String> keys = jCard.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    String valname = valnames.getString(key);
    double valint = valints.getDouble(key);
    // Заносим valname и valint в нужный массив, в нужном формате
};
```

Comment: Я так делал, но почему-то они не по порядку, как в JSON, записываются, а в разнобой. Спасибо и на этом, пришлось применить костыли.